# How to collapse telescope image cone into an optical fiber?

Tags: optics, laser, electrical-engineering, telescopes, fiber-optics

I have an application where a telescope will be receiving light from a laser source. I would like to couple the output of the telescope, which is the image cone, into an optical fiber. Does anyone have any suggestions for the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @EdV, There are 244 hits for "fiber optic" and 87 for "fibre optic" on the electrical engineering Stackexchange, as well as a tag for [fibre-optic]. That said, applied optics questions are at least as likely to get good answers here, and this question fits just fine in the area of applied physics and/or experimental physics, so I would vote to reopen.

Comment: @Anthony, a diagram of your setup would help make your question clearer, and an explanation of how it is relevant to a physics experiment might help get the question reopened.

Comment: Just found this: https://spectroscopy.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/linking-a-telescope-to-a-spectrograph-through-an-optical-fibre-part-i/. I will be trying to understand it. I will delete all my other comments in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard problem in fiber optics called "fiber optic coupling". There are several articles and guides you can find which go over the basics. [Here](https://www.newport.com/n/fiber-optic-coupling) is one for example.

The technique is to try to match the "mode" of the optical fiber and the focused spot after your lens. Usually the manufacturer provides the mode size (i.e. in the case of single mode fibers it is usually about 10 $\mu$m in diameter) and you can choose an appropriate lens to get a focused spot size with a similar size. You would need to mount the fiber on a precision translation stage with micrometer resolution and then monitor the optical power at the other end of the fiber using an optical power meter and adjust the knobs until you have maximum coupling. Typically one can achieve >60% light coupling efficiency into a single mode fiber

Comment: An answer shouldn't only refer elsewhere with links or keywords. You should copy some of the relevant info into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique for obtaining the spectra of many separate stars within the field of view of a telescope is to precisely position the end of a fiber at the location of each star in the image plane of the telescope, and feeding the other end of the fiber into a spectrograph. The astronomy stack exchange might explain how this is done- where to buy the necessary parts, etc.